# Vertical nav with submenu, keeping active class on parent list item when visiting subpages

Tags: jquery, html, jekyll, navigationbar

I'm using Jekyll in conjunction with Compass to build out an interactive prototype. In one of my includes I have a sidebar navigation. The active class is applied to each (li) depending on the active/current URL. Everything works great, until you incorporate the submenu (ul) and various (li > a) for the subpages. I need some way to keep the active class of the parent (li) even when visiting the child pages of that parent.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sidebar">
    <li><a href="pages/group1/somepage1.html">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/group2/somepage2.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="pages/group3/somepage3.html">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu>
            <li><a href="pages/group3/somesubpage1.html">Subitem 1</li>
            <li><a href="pages/group3/somesubpage2.html">Subitem 2</li>
            <li><a href="pages/group3/somesubpage3.html">Subitem 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pages/group4/somepage4.html">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Folder Structure:**

- Pages

  - Group1

    - somepage1.html
  - Group2

    - somepage2.html
  - Group3

    - somepage3.html
    - somesubpage1.html
    - somesubpage2.html
    - somesubpage3.html
  - Group 4

    - somepage4.html

**Goal:**

I want the class called "active" to remain on the parent (li) as I visit each submenu item.

**What I've tried:**

```
$(function(){

    var url = window.location.pathname, 
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
        // now grab every link from the navigation
        $('#sidebar >li a').each(function(){
            // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });

});

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#sidebar li ul.sub-menu li a').click(function(e){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            $('#sidebar li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('a').filter(function(){
        return this.href === window.location.href;
    }).addClass('active')
    $("ul.sub-menu > li > a").each(function () {
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        var thisURL = $(this).attr("href");
        if (currentURL.indexOf(thisURL) != -1) {
            $(this).parents("ul.sub-menu").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
    $('#sidebar > li > a').each(function(){
        var currURL = window.location.href;
        var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
        if (currURL.match(myHref)) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How are your pages located? are somesubpage# in subfolders of somepage?

Comment: @marcanuy I thought about that. No, they're currently all in the same folder. Maybe I should separate them?

Comment: if you have them in subfolders then its path and/or url would contain the parent page, so you can identify them when generating the menu. If not, you can still detect them possibly with the category, if they belong to the somepage category, then generate the active class in somesubpage#..

Comment: @marcanuy so if created a folder structure of "pages/group#" and so "somepage3.html" went into folder group1 and the "somesubpagegroup#.html" pages went into group1 too... so now you'd have "pages/group1/somepage3.html" and if clicked the subitem it would take you to the subpage, which would be "pages/group1/somesubpage1.html" so you'd want to watch for "pages/group1" instead of the full URL... not sure how to modify my script... all help is appreciated

Comment: Please add also the code of the include sidebar navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this via JS, I would loop through each anchor tag in the nav, and once you find a match with the link's `href` address compared to the current page URI, get the link's parent li's, and assign `.active` to the last one (which should be a top-level `li`).

```
var uri = window.location.pathname.substr(1);
$('#sidebar a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href') == uri) {
    $parents = $(this).parents('li').last().addClass('active');
  }
});
```